# Nuxt-auth ..login network header gives me strange path seems like my locale route for login page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

Iam trying to use nuxt-auth module with axios and it gives me "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined" ...and login headers gives strange path 
"Request URL: http://aqar.abdullah.link/api/api/auth/login",any help please???

Nuxt.config.js

```
axios: {
baseURL:'http://aqar.abdullah.link/api',

auth: {
  strategies: {
    local: {
      endpoints: {
        login: { url: '/office/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'data.token' },
        user: { url: '/auth/me', method: 'post', propertyName: false },
        logout: false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

Login Method:

```
 methods:{
 async Login(){
   try{
     await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
        data:{
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password
        }
    })

    this.$router.push('/')

   }catch(e){
     this.error = e.response.data
   }

 },
},
```

[Api response on postman:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mNCa.jpg)

[login page path in folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju7rY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, I used the exact same configurations and it worked for me.
But your `nuxt.config.js` file has a missing closing `},` for the `axios` object.

it should look like this:

```js
  axios: {
    baseURL: "http://aqar.abdullah.link/api"
  },
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: "/office/login",
            method: "post",
            propertyName: "data.token"
          },
          user: { url: "/auth/me", method: "post", propertyName: false },
          logout: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

also make sure you have these modules in you `nuxt.config.js` as well:

```js
  modules: [
    "@nuxt/http",
    "@nuxtjs/auth",
    "@nuxtjs/axios",
  ],
```